# highcharts: how to update marker fillcolor using angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, highcharts

if we use javascript to update specific point maker fill color :

```
chart.series[0].data[0].update({
      marker: {
        fillColor: 'black',
        states: {
          hover: {
            fillColor: 'black',
            lineColor: 'black'
          }
        }
      }
    });
```

but when i try in angularjs controller:

```
Highcharts.charts[0].series[0].data[0].update({  
                                marker: {
                                    fillColor: 'black',
                                    states: {
                                        hover: {
                                            fillColor: 'black',
                                            lineColor: 'black'
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                             });
```

it gives error:

TypeError: Cannot read property 'update' of undefined,

is there way to update marker color using angularjs?

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle sample?

Comment: @ChinmoySamanta, it would be difficult for me to show in jsfiddle as i tried that using javascript it works fine, now i have application in angularjs and want to do the same thing, only problem i'm facing is with updating value, it works fine with  Highcharts.charts[0].series[0].update({ }) but not with adding data[0], thanks.

Comment: Could you do: `console.log(Highcharts.charts[0].series[0])` and post the output here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To update marker fill color,

first store each point color into array based on condition and then update the series with :

```
 angular.forEach($scope.nameofaaray, function (value, i) {

                $scope.valuewithmark[i] = {
                    x:  value.dateData,
                    y: value.actual,
                    marker: {fillColor: $scope.markerFillColor[i]}
                };

        });
```